# Is there any way to programmatically add takeUntil in observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying create an AutoUnsubscribe class, getting all subscriptions used in components with @AutoUnsubscribe decorator and unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy

I already tried get all variables and add takeUntil and it kind of works, but have some problems, example, if I have a component like this:

This is my singleton TestClass to create one observable

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestClass {
  public test$ = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.test$.next(1);
  }
}
```

This is my app component, that we'll use to import TestClass and create a subscription

```
@AutoUnsubscribe()
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private testClass: TestClass) {
     this.testClass.test$
      .subscribe(v => {
        console.log('App component', v);
      });

    this.testClass.test$.next(2);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/teste']);
    }, 4000);
   }
}
```

At this point, the component will start and log "App component 2", and after 4 seconds will redirect to another page, theoretically, canceling all subscriptions

Here is the "/teste" page:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-testpage',
  templateUrl: './testpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testpage.component.scss'],
})
export class TestpageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private testClass: TestClass) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testClass.test$.subscribe(v => {
      console.log('Testpage component', v);
    });

    this.testClass.test$.next(3);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, at this point, the teste page will log:
"App component 3" and after this will log "Testpage component 3"

My @AutoUnsubscribe code its here:

```
export function AutoUnsubscribe(skipList: string[] = []) {
  return function (constructor: any) {
    const onInit = constructor.prototype.ngOnInit;
    const onDestroy = constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy;
    const unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

    constructor.prototype.ngOnInit = function (...args: any[]) {
      for (const prop in this) {
        const property = this[prop];

        if (property && isObservable(property)) {
          console.log(prop, property);
          property.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$));
        }
      }

      if (onInit && typeof onInit === 'function') {
        onInit.apply(this, args);
      }
    };

    constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function (...args: any[]) {
      unsubscribe$.next();
      unsubscribe$.complete();
      unsubscribe$.unsubscribe();

      if (onDestroy && typeof onDestroy === 'function') {
        onDestroy.apply(this, args);
      }
    };
  };
}
```

I tried override the variable with added pipe(takeUntil) but still not working...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend instead of creating your own, just use Angular's [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe. This will automatically subscribe/unsubscribe for you.

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks. When the reference of the expression changes, the async pipe automatically unsubscribes from the old Observable or Promise and subscribes to the new one.

In this example you watch one observable:

```js
@Component({
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="user$ | async as data">
    {{data.firstName}}
  </div>
  `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  user$ = this.service.user$;
  constructor(public readonly service: MyService){}
}
```

In this example you watch multiple observables. Since we are using an object here the properties will at first be undefined so we use the `?` in the template.

```js
@Component({
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="{ 
    a: a$ | async,
    b: b$ | async
  } as data">
    <div>{{data.a?.firstName}}</div>
    <div>{{data.b?.bio}}</div>
  </div>
  `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  a$ = this.service.a$;
  b$ = this.service.b$;
  constructor(public readonly service: MyService){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't realy answer your question but I can point you to a library that do exactly what you want to do: https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy

They solved your problem buy adding a custom operator `untilDestroy`.
I don't know how it's implemented exactly but you can check their source code and see how they did it (it's basically the behaviour of a takeUntil but you don't need to implement the ngOnDestroy and all).

Of course, if you prefer you can also directly use this library (it works like a charm!)

Comment: I already have a decorator like this, but I don't want add manually "untilDestroy" or "takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)", I would like to make automatically

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment on the other answer, you cannot just use the decorator or just the operator.

You cannot use just the decorator because you have no **clean** way of knowing a subscrpition is created.

You cannot just use an operator because then, you have no way of knowing when to unsubscribe.

If you want to achieve what you want, the way you want, you will have to wait for Angular 16 and its `destroyRef` operator.

Comment: Ohhh thanks, ill wait angular 16 unfortunately